# creating multiple instances of microservice and pointing each instance to its respective configurations dynamically

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I know there is a way (setting the port to 0) to create multiple instances of a microservice dynamically.

My requirement is, I have a set of multiple clients and each client will have its corresponding business logic implemented its corresponding implementation class.

I have a factory method design pattern to return me the corresponding implementation class based on the client ID I pass to the factory method.

I want to deploy it as a microservice for one client. For the remaining clients, the microservice should be instantiated dynamically for each client ID and its corresponding implementation class should process its business logic based on the client ID passed to the factory method.

Is it possible technically using spring cloud?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are asking. Are you talking about deployment or hosting multiple services in a single process?

Answer (score 0):

If your service already has the business logic implemented for every client, I don't quite understand why you would want to instantiate another micro service for every client. The one service already deployed should work if you can manage to send in the client ids.

If the deployment is on client's servers, it's not a good idea to have all the clients' business logic code in one service.

Comment: Our design is updated a little bit.Our requirement is to have the business logic implemented for multiple clients based on their requirement. Some clients would have the similar business requirements except pointing to a different datasource.So, we are planning to deploy business logic implemented for each client as a microservice and instantiate as multiple instance of the microservice having the similar requirement based configurations of that particular client. is it possible to have access to the instance of the microservice of a particular client based on the config details?